# Oracle Join Two Queries With Distinct Answer

Tags: oracle, join, distinct

I need help in linking two tables together to bring back data as I need.
I have two queries:
The first is as follows:

```
    SELECT 
        POI.PO_ID as PO_ID, SUM(POI.INV_QTY) AS INV_QTY, POI.INV_NUMBER, 
        PO.SUP_SUP_ID AS SUPPLIER

    FROM TABLE1 POI, PUR_ORDS PO
    WHERE POI.PO_ID = '56886' AND POI.PO_ID = PO.PO_ID
    GROUP BY POI.PO_ID, POI.INV_NUMBER, PO.SUP_SUP_ID
    ORDER BY POI.INV_NUMBER ASC
```

The Results of this query are as follows:

```
PO_ID|INV_QTY|INV_NUMBER|SUPPLIER
---------------------------------
56886|    105|INV1      |SUP1
56886|    106|INV2      |SUP1
```

The second query I have is this:

```
    SELECT 
        DIL.PO_PO_ID, sum(DIL.ACPTD_QTY) as ACPTD_QTY, 
        DIL.DLVD_DLVY_NUMB AS DEL_NUM
    FROM TABLE2 DIL
    where DIL.PO_PO_ID = '56886'
    GROUP BY PO_PO_ID, DIL.DLVD_DLVY_NUMB
    order by del_num
```

The Results of this query are as follows:

```
PO_PO_ID|ACPTD_QTY|DEL_NUM
--------------------------
   56886|      105|      1
   56886|      106|      2
```

Now I am attempting to join the two tables, but I get multiple values appearing, using the following:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(PO_ID), INV_NUMBER, INV_QTY, SUPPLIER, ACPTD_QTY, DEL_NUM
FROM
(SELECT 
            SELECT POI.PO_ID as PO_ID, SUM(POI.INV_QTY) AS INV_QTY, 
                POI.INV_NUMBER, PO.SUP_SUP_ID AS SUPPLIER
            FROM TABLE1 POI, PUR_ORDS PO
            WHERE POI.PO_ID = '56886'
            AND POI.PO_ID = PO.PO_ID
            GROUP BY POI.PO_ID, POI.INV_NUMBER, PO.SUP_SUP_ID
            ORDER BY POI.INV_NUMBER ASC) POINET
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DIL.PO_PO_ID, sum(DIL.ACPTD_QTY) as ACPTD_QTY, 
                DIL.DLVD_DLVY_NUMB AS DEL_NUM
            FROM TABLE 2 DIL
            where DIL.PO_PO_ID = '56886'
            GROUP BY PO_PO_ID, DIL.DLVD_DLVY_NUMB
            order by DEL_NUM) DILV

            ON DILV.PO_PO_ID = POINET.PO_ID
            GROUP BY PO_ID, INV_NUMBER, INV_QTY, SUPPLIER, ACPTD_QTY, DEL_NUM
            ORDER BY INV_NUMBER
```

However the dataset I get is this:

```
PO_ID|INV_NUMBER   |INV_QTY|SUPPLIER|ACPTD_QTY|DEL_NUM
-----------------------------------------------------
56886|K-101/2014-15|    105|SUP1    |      105|     1
56886|K-101/2014-15|    105|SUP1    |      106|     2
56886|K-107/2014-15|    106|SUP1    |      105|     1
56886|K-107/2014-15|    106|SUP1    |      106|     2
```

However I need it show the following:

```
PO_ID|INV_NUMBER   |INV_QTY|SUPPLIER|ACPTD_QTY|DEL_NUM
------------------------------------------------------
56886|K-101/2014-15|    105|SUP1    |      105|      1
56886|K-107/2014-15|    106|SUP1    |      106|      2
```

What do I need to do, to tweak my query?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us your tables contraints?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to modify your join statement to join on both columns

```
ON DILV.PO_PO_ID = POINET.PO_ID
AND DILV.INV_QTY = POINET.ACPTD_QTY
```

Actually, you can probably leave out the PO_ID, because I it's the same in both subqueries:

i.e. Just do this (on the third last line):

```
ON DILV.INV_QTY = POINET.ACPTD_QTY
```

Comment: Hi

DILV.INV_QTY and POINET.ACPTD_QTY always will differ and will never actually be the same. So there can be an instance where you book on INV_QTY might be 10 and ACPTD_QTY might be 14

Comment: OK - that wasn't clear from your description. The reason why you're getting multiple rows is because you're effectively doing a cartesian join on your subqueries because the PO_ID is always the same. You need some sort of identifier in both subqueries that allows you to join them uniquely. Without example records (of the underlying data) it's very difficult to see what that should be.

Comment: Hi mlinth, thanks for your response, unfortuantely the only way to link the two tables is by PO_ID, there is no other way of a link. So I am not sure if this is possible or if it is, how I can achieve this.

Thanks
Harmz